# RoR: Carrierwave Not Working/Saving to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

This is my hacked together attempt at getting Carrierwave to work right from watching Railscast. I have a Post Project page where users enter in details for a project. They can also upload a file to this page, and submit the project. So I am using a nested_form_for on the page.

new_step_3.html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for @project, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

    <%= f.fields_for :document do |attachment_form| %>
      <%= attachment_form.file_field :title %>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.text_field :skills %>
  <%= f.submit 'Post Project' %>
<% end %>
```

project.rb model

```
attr_accessible :category, :title, :budget, :end_date, :description, :skills, :document, :days_lasting, :documents_attributes

belongs_to :user
has_many :posts
has_many :documents, :as => :attachable

validates_presence_of :category, :title, :description, :skills

accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
```

document.rb model

```
attr_accessible :project_id, :title, :document

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
has_many :posts

mount_uploader :document, DocumentUploader
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def create
@project = current_user.projects.build(params[:project])

respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
    format.html { redirect_to project_step_4_path(:start => @project.id), notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Right now, when I try to submit the form, it will say unknown attribute: document
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:85:in `create'

Running the command in Rails console works Document.create!(:document => File.new("test.jpg"))

Comment: Does your underlying DB schema have a varchar "document" column in the "documents" table?

Comment: It does since he's saying it works fine in the console ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :documents do |attachment_form| %>
  <%= attachment_form.file_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

with fields_for :**documents**

That's why it's not finding the `document` attribute. Your form probably sends a hash like that:

```
{
  :project => {
    :title => "blabla",
    :document => {...}
  }
}
```

and it doesnt know what to do with the document.
Now your nested documents will be in :documents => {}, and with the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, it should work.

You have to `build` a document for this project in the controller:

```
@project.documents.build
```

Comment: Hey Robin, Thanks for the answer. When I do it now; the file_field doesn't show up in the views.

Comment: I think it might be because you have to `build` one. So in your controller, do `@project.documents.build`.